# Query to pull user data from meta data table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble figuring out whats wrong with this query. I have a wordpress site where I am trying to pull the user data from wp_users and wp_usermeta. Here is the query I currently have. It only pulls a certain amount of users instead of all.

```
SELECT wp_users.id AS ID
    ,metafn.meta_value AS "First Name"
    ,metaln.meta_value AS "Last Name"
    ,wp_users.user_email AS "Email"
    ,metap.meta_value AS "Phone"
    ,metaad.meta_value AS "Address"
    ,metac.meta_value AS "City"
    ,metas.meta_value AS "State"
    ,metapc.meta_value AS "Zip"
    ,metad.meta_value AS "Money Donated"
FROM wp_users
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta metafn ON (
        wp_users.ID = metafn.user_id
        AND metafn.meta_key = 'first_name'
        )
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta metaln ON (
        wp_users.ID = metaln.user_id
        AND metaln.meta_key = 'last_name'
        )
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta metap ON (
        wp_users.ID = metap.user_id
        AND metap.meta_key = 'billing_phone'
        )
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta metaad ON (
        wp_users.ID = metaad.user_id
        AND metaad.meta_key = 'billing_address_1'
        )
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta metac ON (
        wp_users.ID = metac.user_id
        AND metac.meta_key = 'billing_city'
        )
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta metas ON (
        wp_users.ID = metas.user_id
        AND metas.meta_key = 'billing_state'
        )
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta metapc ON (
        wp_users.ID = metapc.user_id
        AND metapc.meta_key = 'billing_postcode'
        )
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta metad ON (
        wp_users.ID = metad.user_id
        AND metad.meta_key = '_money_spent'
        )
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM donors
        WHERE donors.user_id = wp_users.id
        )
```

Sorry for the formating. Any help would be awesome thanks!

Comment: Please explain *how* your query isn't working for you.  What are you trying to do?  Can you please provide sample data and an expected result?

Comment: This is just a guess, but I think your where clause should be something like where wp_users.id not in (select user_id from donors)

Comment: Im not getting all the users and user meta data from the tables. It will randomly leave out a few users. Even without the where clause it still misses users.

Comment: I figured it out guys thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I found out I needed to change the join statement to LEFT JOIN instead of INNER. I did not realize there were some null values in my data which were not showing up when using an INNER JOIN. Thanks!